# Define base class method working on derived class collection

Tags: c#, inheritance, covariance

I'm trying to put a generic *Add* method in my base class that will work on different types of classes, all implementing *ICollection*. So far so good, I'm able to use boxing/unboxing to achieve what I want, but I wonder if there is a better way to do this. I've played little with covariant interface, but without greater luck - is it even possible to define *IVariantCollection*?

Here is a pice of code that should explain what I try to achieve:

```cs
public abstract class Device
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract void Print();
}

public class Printer : Device { public override void Print() => Debug.WriteLine($"{Name} printer printout"); }

public class Xero : Device { public override void Print() => Debug.WriteLine($"{Name} xero printout."); }

public abstract class Factory
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<Device> DeviceCollection { get; }
    public abstract void Add(object added);
    public void ListDevices() { foreach (var item in DeviceCollection) Debug.WriteLine($"Device: {item.Name}"); }
}

public class PrinterFactory : Factory
{
    public List<Printer> Printers = new List<Printer>();
    public override IEnumerable<Device> DeviceCollection => Printers;

    public override void Add(object added) { Printers.Add((Printer)added); }
}

public class XeroFactory : Factory
{
    public ObservableCollection<Xero> Xeros = new ObservableCollection<Xero>();
    public override IEnumerable<Device> DeviceCollection => Xeros;

    public XeroFactory() { Xeros.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine($"Device added: {e.NewItems[0]}"); }
    public override void Add(object added) { Xeros.Add((Xero)added); }
}
```

The code works, but I somehow don't like this solution with *object* - is there other way to define *Add* method, maybe a generic one in base class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use generic `Factory` with base class constraint

```cs
public abstract class Factory<TDevice> where TDevice : Device
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<TDevice> DeviceCollection { get; }
    public abstract void Add(TDevice added);
    public void ListDevices() 
        { 
            foreach (var item in DeviceCollection) 
                Debug.WriteLine($"Device: {item.Name}"); 
        }
}
```

Then

```
public class PrinterFactory : Factory<Printer>
{
    public List<Printer> Printers = new List<Printer>();
    public override IEnumerable<Printer> DeviceCollection => Printers;

    public override void Add(Printer added) { Printers.Add(added); }
}
```

Comment: You are right - in this case to do what I want, I don't need variance and simple generics will be enough. Damn, I knew I was close, I've just started reading too much about variance. In your solution with generics, it is also possible to put *ICollection* instead of *IEnumerable*, what makes possible to define *Add* method in `Device` class.